# Providing Access to package level variable via public getter - How to return the instance?

Tags: go, pointers

I have a package level variable that I instantiate at the startup of the application. Even though it is declared to be package level, I need to access it from outside the package as well. To do that, I have a function that returns the variable.

```
package app

var myService MyService

type MyService interface {
    DoThis()
    DoThat()
}

func Initialize() {
    
    // initialise other stuff
    myService = initMyService()

}

func GetMyService() MyService {
    return myService
}
```

Now from outside of the app package, when I need to do something with MyService, I do following.

```
ms := app.GetMyService()
ms.DoThis()
```

Here I have following questions.

1. Doesn't the GetMyService() function return copies of myService each time it is invoked?
2. If that is the case, if I return a pointer to the myService inside that function, does it solve that problem by returning a reference to the single myService instance that was initially instantiated?

Comment: either way, `GetMyService` returns an interface, which boxes the concrete value. So for the client code, it's transparent

Comment: but just in case - yes, it's coping value to the stack.

Comment: @blackgreen yes it boxes the actual implementation. but doesn't it box a copy of myService each time it is called?

Comment: There are no references in Go.

Comment: @Volker i mean a pointer

Answer (score 3):

`var myService MyService` here `MyService` is an `interface`. So you can implement it with pointer receiver methods or value receiver methods.

As go tour [tour.golang.org/methods/8](https://tour.golang.org/methods/8) mentioned,

> There are two reasons to use a pointer receiver.
>
> The first is so that the method can modify the value that its receiver
> points to.
>
> The second is to avoid copying the value on each method call. This can
> be more efficient if the receiver is a large struct...

If you implement `MyService` with pointer receiver methods, It will not copy the receiver in every call.

And please refer `golang.org/doc/faq` [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers). There is a good explanation for it too.

sample implementation like below

```
type doer struct {
    // any fields   
}

func (d *doer) DoThis() {
    // any implementation
    fmt.Println(`do this`)
}

func (d *doer) DoThat() {
    // any implementation
    fmt.Println(`do that`)
}

func initMyService()  MyService{
    return &doer{
        // init doer fields
    }
}
```

Comment: the decision of making them pointer receivers solely depends on the implmentation of the function. isn't it? If you need to modify the fields in the structs inside the receiver function, yes u have to make them pointer receivers. In my case, let's say it just print something to the console. the functions does not expose the fields to others. In that case, I think you dont have to make them pointer receivers.

Comment: And other point, If your receiver type is not large to copy in every function call. As go faq described at last `For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.`